# Python: limit on string length when using isalpha

Tags: python, string

First off - I am completely new to python and to programming so bear with me.

Trying to solve the popular python challenge #2, I created the below code to parse a long string of mostly gibberish and extract the letters from it. I no it's not elegant and there are much more streamlined and efficient ways of doing it. However, it works for whatever I type into the input, but with the (long) input that is required in the challenge it only outputs a single letter - 'e' - when the complete set of letters present is 'equality'. Any thoughts appreciated, here is the code:

```
def alpha(string):
        i = 0
        answer = ""
        length = len(string)
        while i < length:
                if string[i].isalpha():
                        answer += string[i]
                i += 1
        return answer

def get_input():
        alpha = raw_input("input: ")
        return alpha

get_input = get_input()
alpha = alpha(get_input)

print alpha
```

Comment: What is this challenge? Can you give a link, I'm curious

Comment: http://www.pythonchallenge.com

I believe it can be solved using other languages (or scripting) as well, but the author meant it for python.

Comment: For reference, the string is over 9000 characters long. Here is a sample:

%%$@_$^__#)^)&!_+]!*@&^}@[@%]()%+$&[(_@%+%$*^@$^!+]!&_#)_*}{}}!}_]$[%}@[{_@#_^{*@##&{#&{&)*%(]{{([*}@[@&]+!!*{)!}{%+{))])[!^})+)$]#{*+^((@^@}$[**$&^{$!@#$%)!@(&+^!{%_$&@^!}$_${)$_#)!({@!)(^}!*^&!$%_&&}&_#&@{)]{+)%*{&*%*&@%$+]!*__(#!*){%&@++!_)^$&&%#+)}!@!)&^}**#!_$([$!$}#*^}$+&#

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join(ch for ch in get_input if ch.isalpha())
```

Your code then can be reduced to following:

```
get_input  = raw_input("input: ")
alpha = ''.join(ch for ch in get_input if ch.isalpha())
print alpha
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but only to the same extent as my code. I think it may have to do with the computer on which I'm running it - a virtual ubuntu machine on digitalocean. Perhaps it has a limit to how much input it can receive in its python implementation.

Comment: @J314159, I don't quite understand your problem here. Are you saying that this would work for the case where the length of `get_input` is small. While when the `get_input` string size gets larger, my code cannot work? If this is the case, how large is the `get_input`?

Comment: The get_input is over 9000 characters. As I mentioned, perhaps it has to do with the computer (remote virtual running Ubuntu) that I am running it on as neither your script nor mine works for such a long string.